# how to get a grid of different sizes using css and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dynamically created grid with  images  of different sizes how do i get a tiled gallary

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="block1">
      <img src="img1" />
   </div>
   <div class="block2">
      <img src="img1" />
   </div>
   <div class="block3">
      <img src="img1" />
   </div>
   <div class="block4">
      <img src="img1" />
   </div>
</div>
```

I do not want to use third party libraries any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize your images by JavaScript. For example, this code will resize each img at the maximumHeight value.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/FU76g/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" id="container">
   <div class="block1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   </div>
   <div class="block2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   </div>
   <div class="block3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x200" />
   </div>
   <div class="block4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var container_div = document.getElementById("container"); 
var array_img=container_div.getElementsByTagName("img");

var maxHeight=0;

for(var index = 0; index < array_img.length; index++){
    if (array_img[index].clientHeight > maxHeight){
        maxHeight = array_img[index].clientHeight;
    }
}

alert("will do");
for(index = 0; index < array_img.length; index++){
    array_img[index].height = maxHeight;
}
alert("done");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicolas this was what i was looking ,is there any way we could use style display:inline-block ,so that it fills up the gap

Comment: Add this CSS rule: .container div{display:inline-block;}